# Insert enabled Button into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Goal is to insert enabled `Button` into a `DataGrid` column.

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="DgData"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="306" Margin="10,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="637" Background="White">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsNewItem,Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Date}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Doménové jméno" Binding="{Binding DomainName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="105" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Druh" Binding="{Binding Relevance}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="65" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kategorie" Binding="{Binding DomainName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="65" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Popis" Binding="{Binding Content}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="100" Header="Poznámky" CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="BtnShowNotes" IsEnabled="True" Click="BtnShowNotes_OnClick">Zobrazit</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Button (`TemplateColumn`) properties:
[image]

When using WPF solution buttons are disabled:

[image]

When using WinForms solution buttons are enabled:

[image]

How to enable buttons using WPF solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RowStyle` sets the `IsEnabled` property of the entire row to `false`. Remove this one and the `Button` should be enabled:

```
<DataGrid Name="DgData"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="306" Margin="10,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="637" Background="White">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Date}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Doménové jméno" Binding="{Binding DomainName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="105" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Druh" Binding="{Binding Relevance}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="65" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kategorie" Binding="{Binding DomainName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="65" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Popis" Binding="{Binding Content}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="100" Header="Poznámky" CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="BtnShowNotes" IsEnabled="True" Click="BtnShowNotes_OnClick">Zobrazit</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```